# Why doesn't the NetworkImage radius property work? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I can't understand why my image, gotten from the network doesn't have a BorderRadius.
Tell me please where did I error?
I thought I needed to take a smaller image, but that didn't work for me either.

```
Widget customListTile({
  required String title,
  required String singer,
  required String cover,
  onTap
}){
  return InkWell(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: 80.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(cover)
              )
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10.0,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              Text(
                singer,
                style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 16.0
              ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I tried different ways to wrap the xset image in different widgets, but that didn't work for me either, I don't understand why. Please help me deal with this problem!
This my result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
                                        ClipRRect(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                                child: Image.network(
                                                  cover,
                                                  width: 80,
                                                  height: 80,
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                ),
                                              ),
...
```

Use `ClipRRect()`

Comment: Oh, yes, its helped for me. Thank you friend, you are superman!!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to fill the image, you need to use `fit` property and it will clip by default, if fails to clip, use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` on Container.

```dart
child: Container(
  height: 180.0,
  width: 180.0,
 // clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, //enable if needed
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage(
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/ed2e069ee37807f5975a.jpg",
        scale: 1,
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]